# Firebase Push Notification with Laravel 5.6

Tags: php, firebase, laravel-5, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am asking for help in push notification (especially Firebase Cloud Messaging : FCM). I already have checked the official documentation about it and it was pretty clear but i just wanna know how to have a simple summary of implementation of it using PHP Laravel 5.6 and what's the best practices on it .
Thank you in advance for your help.
I checked the official documentation of Firebase Cloud Messaging

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.